# Does loading .php files that you don't use affect performance?

Tags: php

Just wondering... Does it? And how much

Like including 20 .php files whith classes in them, but without actually using the classes (they might be used though).

Comment: It may cost you a bit of performance, depending on your system and how big they are. You'd have to measure for yourself how much it costs. You could use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to load the files on demand

Comment: This is why design patterns exist with loaders, yes it does effect performance: speed (the include) and memory (included file contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give a slight variant Answer to this:

- If you are running on a tuned VPS or dedicated server: a trivial amount.
- If you are running on a shared hosting service: it can considerably degrade performance of your script execution time.

Why? because in the first case you should have configured a PHP opcode cache such as APC or Xcache, which can, in practical terms, eliminate script load and compilation overheads.  Even where files need to be read or stat-checked the meta and file data will be "hot" and therefore largely cached in the file-system cache if the (virtual) server is dedicated to the application.

On a shared service everything is running in the opposite direction: PHP is run as a per-request image in the users UID; no opcode caching solutions support this mode, so everything needs to be compiled.  The killer here is that files need to be read and many (perhaps most) shared LAMP hosting providers use a scalable server farm for the LAMP tier, with the user data on shared NFS mounted NAS infrastructure.  Since these NFS mounts with have an **acremin** of less than 1 min, the I/O requests will require RPCs off-server. My blog article gives some benchmarks [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-44).  The details for a shared IIS hosting template are different but the net effects are similar.

I run the phpBB forum package on my shared service and I roughly halved response times by aggregating the common set of source includes as I describe [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-53).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, though by how much depends on a number of things. The performance cost isn't too high if you are using a PHP accelerator, but will drastically slow things if you're aren't. Your best bet is generally to use autoloading, so you only load things at the point of actual use, rather than loading everything just in case. That may reduce your memory consumption too.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it affects the performance. Everything you do in PHP does.

How much performance is a matter of how much data is in them, and how long it takes to execute them or in the case of classes, read them.

If your not using them, why include them? I assume your using some main engine file, or header file and should rethink your methods of including files.

**EDIT:** Or as @Pekka pointed out, you can autoload classes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes it will.
For longer answers a quick google search revealed these - [Will including unnecessary php files slow down website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198253/will-including-unnecessary-php-files-slow-down-website) ; [PHP Performance on including multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140391/php-performance-on-including-multiple-files)

Searching helps!

--Matīss